# Find $\lim_{(x\rightarrow 0^{+})} \frac{\ln(x+\arccos^{3}x)-\ln x}{x^{2}}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find  $\lim_{(x\rightarrow 0^{+})} \frac{\ln(x+\arccos^{3}x)-\ln x}{x^{2}}$.

---

After some basic steps, I reached to $\frac{\ln(x+\arccos^{3}x)-\ln x}{x^{2}}= \frac{\ln(1+\frac{\arccos^{3}x}{x})}{x^{2}}$. I intended to use Sandwich theorem because $0\leq  \arccos^{3}x\leq  \pi ^{3}$, but it did't seem to work. Can I have others ways to approach for the problem? Please help me, thank you so much!

Comment: This expression diverges to infinity. Just use $\arccos x\approx\pi/2$

Comment: @Andrei Can you explain more? Please.

Comment: Can you show that $1/x^2$ goes to infinity as $x\to 0^+$? Then you multiply this quantity with a number greater than $1$.

Comment: To get $\ln(1+\frac{\arccos^3 x}{x^2})\approx\ln(1+\frac{\pi^3}8\frac1{x^2})$. For small $x$, this term is going to infinity

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Andrei , when you carefully observe, the expression is of the form

$$\frac{\infty}{0}\to\infty$$

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @Mohith7548 This is not an indeterminate form

Comment: I still don't understand why we have this, please show me.

Answer (score 0):

If you compose Taylor series around $x=0$
$$\cos ^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi }{2}-x+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\cos ^{-1}(x)^3=\frac{\pi ^3}{8}-\frac{3 \pi ^2 x}{4}+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$1+\frac{\cos ^{-1}(x)^3}{x}=\frac{\pi ^3}{8 x}+1-\frac{3 \pi ^2}{4}+O\left(x^1\right)$$